# Deploy Source to ORG - Invalid type: Schema.SOBJECT

Tags: apex, visualforce

i'm having a "SFDX: Deploy Source to Org failed to run" ERROR! Tried everything i could but no success, could you friends help me solve this problem please?

It says too - Invalid type: Schema.SOBJECT (1:9)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The default code when you create a trigger with SFDX reads as:

```
trigger Demo on SOBJECT (before insert) {

}
```

*(Where `Demo` is the name of the trigger that you supplied to Salesforce DX or the VS Code Extension Bundle)*

Once you save this file, it should deploy correctly.

You can tell the file isn't saved, because it has a circle next to the name ("AccountTrigger.trigger ●"). Once saved correctly, it will turn into an x symbol ("AccountTrigger.trigger ×").

Comment: Tyvm my friend!